# Groovy Script: No signature of method

Tags: groovy

I get the below error, and am confused as it seems to type-match just fine (Possible Solutions vs. Values):

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.xxx.www.ci.yyy.GetRecords() is applicable for argument types: (com.xxx.www.ci.yyy$GetRecords) values: [com.xxx.www.ci.yyy$GetRecords@75e1a893]
Possible solutions: getRecords(com.xxx.www.ci.yyy$GetRecords)
```

Parts of the script:

```
import com.xxx.www.ci.yyy
import com.xxx.www.ci.yyy.Get
import com.xxx.www.ci.yyy.GetRecords
import com.xxx.www.ci.yyy.GetRecordsResponse
import com.xxx.www.ci.yyy.GetKeys
import com.xxx.www.ci.yyy.GetKeysResponse

public class CIAdapter  implements Serializable{

 private def checkCI(event, PasswordAuthentication credentials) {
     yyy client = new yyy()     
     HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuthentication  = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator() 
     basicAuthentication. setUsername ( "user" ) 
     basicAuthentication. setPassword ( "pwd" )

    def getCI = new yyy.GetRecords()
    def resp = new yyy.GetRecordsResponse() 

    getCI.__encoded_query = "selection"
    resp = client.GetRecords(getCI)

    return resp
  }
}
```

I've tried with coercion, (i.e. "yyy.GetRecords getCI = new yyy.GetRecords()") but with the same results. I am going round in circles, so it must be something obvious I am missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: client.GetRecords(getCI) there is no such function...

Comment: I knew I was looking at it myopically! Thank you! It was a case of the wrong case for the method. Can you make this an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error: there is no such function

and obviously in this line:

```
client.GetRecords(getCI)
```

because there is no other cases where you call `GetRecords` with parameter